# Node - Post request showing undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angular

Im making a angular2/Node.js application. Right now when i try to get a object from the node server, it returns just fine. However, when i try to post data to the node server. The request.body shows undefined. What am i doing wrong ?

server.js

```
// Test
router.get('/test', function (req, res) {
    res.json({test:true}); // Works 
});

// Post
router.post('/rest', function (req, res) {
    var body = req.body;
    console.log(body); // Undefined 
    res.json({test:true});
});
```

app.ts

```
constructor(private http:Http){
    console.log("Test")
    http.get('/api/User/test').subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result.json());
    });
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    this.http.post('/api/User/rest',{test:'Testing req'},{headers:headers})
    .subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result.json());
    });  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install body-parser?

```
npm install body-parser --save
```

and before your routes, add it to your express application

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

see also: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: Im an idoit i forgot the app.use(bodyParser.json()); part. Thanks

Comment: @Aj_ I am also an idiot, your comment  helped. Thanks